# how to make seaborn sort by ascending values when plotting?

Tags: python, seaborn

I am using the sns.regplot function to plot two numerical variables that I uploaded from a CSV. Both variables are numerical, yet when I plot them, neither of the axes are in numerical order. Where did I go wrong? [picture below]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbbH8.png)

I used sns.regplot before, but it has never failed to sort them in ascending values.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You need to convert your values from strings to numeric.   Also note that your question is missing reproducible code and test data, as required per StackOverflow guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

may be you can try with the below :

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Assuming you have imported your data and assigned the numerical variables to x and y

# Sort the data based on the x-axis values
sorted_data = sorted(zip(x, y), key=lambda pair: pair[0])
sorted_x, sorted_y = zip(*sorted_data)

# Create the scatter plot with regression line using sorted data
sns.regplot(x=sorted_x, y=sorted_y)

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```